# How to detect user interaction with graphstream?

Tags: android, graphstream

I am investigating the use of GraphStream on Android using

```
api 'com.github.graphstream:gs-ui-android:2.0-alpha'
api 'com.github.graphstream:gs-core:2.0-alpha'
```

I have managed to construct and display my Graph fine,

However I cannot see how to listen for user interactions on the nodes within my graph.

I need to display a Dialog when any node is clicked on by the user and display the specific nodes information.

I've tried setting a Listener on the `org.graphstream.ui.android_viewer.AndroidViewer`, however I never received any callbacks

I can drag the displayed nodes around the screen so I know there are default listeners, how to I add my own listeners though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement ViewerListener with the ViewerPipe like this :

```
ViewerPipe pipe = fragment.getViewer().newViewerPipe();

pipe.addAttributeSink( graph );
pipe.addViewerListener( this ); // this or any class which implements ViewerListener
pipe.pump();
```

You can get an exemple here : https://github.com/graphstream/gs-ui-android-test/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ui/graphstream/org/gs_ui_androidtestFull/Activity_TestArrows.java

And here to understand how ViewerPipe works : http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/